Password Hash Parameters
Looking at the /etc/auth.defs, I know that my Fedora Workstation 41 uses yescrypt to hash password before storing them in /etc/shadow/. Is it possible to know (and set) the parameters that are passed to yescrypt?

Edit--I have posted in the comment section the interpretation of the values found in /etc/shadow/, as explained by a gentlemen in Unix&Linux (in addition to my personal guesses). However, I still want a means to know the explicit configuration of yescrypt, and how to configure it myself.

Referring to this answer, you can find the parameters from the /etc/shadow file. There, you'll find (1) the algorithm used; (2) the parameters; (3) the salt and (4) the hash.
Taking for instance $y$j9T$PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31$G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5.

1. The y refers to (y)escrypt;
2. The j9T refers to the parameters (my target);
3. The PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31 refers to the salt; and 
4. The G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5 refers to the password hash.

As for the parameters, the j is used to refer to YESCRYPT_DEFAULTS; the 9 translates to 4096 in yescrypt variable-length encoding, and is the value of N; and T translates to 32 in yescrypt variable-length encoding, and is the value of r. N and r are two parameters of the yescrypt. I assume that p is set to 1 as the default (as recommended by the algorithm developers), and that t, g and NROM are all set to 0.\
